# How to compile dlib under make with multiple files?

Tags: c++, makefile, dlib

Recently I've been trying to add dlib library to my project (I am interested in MPC part since I want it to control a quadrocopter), despite many different approaches I couldn't find a proper working solution.
I have a makefile like this:

```
all : quadro_mini
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -lpthread -O3 #-Wall -pedantic
LIBRARIES = -IMPU6050 -LMPU6050 -IHCSR04 -LHCSR04

OBJS = Steer.o Measurer.o LogWriter.o Server.o Functions.o Engine.o EnginesManager.o main.o 
HDRS = Server.h Measurer.h LogWriter.h Functions.h SteeringSignalsListener.h Engine.h EnginesManager.h Constants.h Steer.h 

$(OBJS) : $(HDRS) 

quadro_mini : $(OBJS)
    g++ -pthread $^ $(LIBRARIES) -lMPU6050 -lHCSR04 -DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT -o $@
```

I want to use dlib in Steer.o module

**First approach**
Linking to header containing all necessary includes

```
OBJS = Measurer.o LogWriter.o Server.o Functions.o Engine.o EnginesManager.o main.o dlib/control.o #nazwy sie musza zgadzac z nazwami *.cpp i *.h
HDRS = Server.h Measurer.h LogWriter.h Functions.h SteeringSignalsListener.h Engine.h EnginesManager.h Constants.h Steer.h 

$(OBJS) : $(HDRS) 

Steer.o : $(HDRS)
   g++ $(CXXFLAGS) $^ $(LIBRARIES) -I. dlib/control.h -o $@
quadro_mini : $(OBJS) Steer.o
    g++ -pthread $^ $(LIBRARIES) -lMPU6050 -lHCSR04 -DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT -o $@
```

The output I receive:

```
In file included from dlib/control/../matrix/matrix_exp.h:6:0,
             from dlib/control/../matrix/matrix.h:6,
             from dlib/control/../matrix.h:6,
             from dlib/control/approximate_linear_models.h:7,
             from dlib/control/lspi.h:7,
             from dlib/control.h:6,
             from Steer.h:10:
dlib/control/../matrix/../algs.h:146:9: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
dlib/control/../matrix/../algs.h:146:9: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
dlib/control/../matrix/../algs.h:146:9: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
dlib/control/../matrix/../algs.h:495:14: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'disable_if_c'
dlib/control/../matrix/../algs.h:495:26: error: expected initializer before '<' token
dlib/control/../matrix/../algs.h:510:14: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'enable_if_c'
dlib/control/../matrix/../algs.h:510:25: error: expected initializer before '<' token
dlib/control/../matrix/../algs.h:627:48: error: 'uint64' was not declared in this scope
dlib/control/../matrix/../algs.h:627:48: note: suggested alternative:
```

etc.

**Second aproach:**
Making library out of it

```
all: dlib.a

CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11 -pthread -DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT

dlib.o : control.h
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ 

dlib.a: dlib.o
    ar -rv $@ $^
```

But since everything is header in dlib then what header should I include ? None... since official page forbids from adding it to compiler's include path. Then this approach still doesn't work... just for info - compile artifacts take over 60 mb.

**Third approach**
Adding the folder that contains the dlib folder to include search path and then use include statements of the form #include  (dlib official statement).

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/linaro/Quadrocopter/dlib
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Also

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/linaro/Quadrocopter/
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

First gives:

```
/home/linaro/Quadrocopter/dlib/dlib_include_path_tutorial.txt:1:2: error: #error "Don't put the dlib folder in your include path"
```

etc.
Second has similar effect as First Approach

I've also created test build with only 2 compilation artifacts:

```
all : test
CXXFLAGS = -g -O3 -std=c++11
LFLAGS = -lpthread -lnsl 

OBJS = maintest.o LogWriter.o
HDRS = LogWriter.h Constants.h

$(OBJS) : $(HDRS)

test : $(OBJS) 
    g++ -pthread -Idlib/control.h $^ -o $@
```

And this is working ! Yet it cannot with my previous makefile

Anyone please help me with this ? (and no -Ldlib is also not working)

Environment: Custom Lubuntu,  gcc version 4.7.2, GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 1):

Let us proceed in small steps. Try this, and tell us the result:

```
HDRS = Server.h Measurer.h LogWriter.h Functions.h SteeringSignalsListener.h Engine.h EnginesManager.h Constants.h Steer.h

Measurer.o : Measurer.cpp $(HDRS) 
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) $< -I. -o $@
```

Comment: After I add: Steer.o : Steer.cpp $(HDRS) 
                     g++ $(CXXFLAGS) $< -I. -o $@   (I think that you were meaning Steer.o ? not measurer.o ?).  I am receiving same result as with the first approach.

Comment: @lagoru: That is interesting. Now try what I suggested. And don't *add*. Try a makefile that contains what I wrote above, and nothing else.

Comment: After two weeks of fighting with it I've finally found a solution - it wasn't connected with linking at all. In my last seemingly pointless attempt to find solution. I've copied everything on temporary system, and updated gcc. After I had linked it normally and started build it showed me that global variable of dlib "TIMEOUT" is in conflict with my global #define TIMEOUT..., gcc on Lubuntu is just showing rubbish not connected with problem at all (several thousands lines of non related with case errors). Thanks nevertherless, since you were the only one interested ;)